# How Do I Generate a DIV table from a form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to generate a DIV table header row using the JavaScript (no jQuery) shown below but rather than the expected output shown here, what I generate is a row of the items in the array (the headings separated by commas).

[image: Div Table heading]

```js
var main = document.getElementById("left");

  var likertTable = document.createElement("DIV"); //main table div
  likertTable.setAttribute("class", "divTable");

  var tableHeading = document.createElement("DIV"); // table heading
  tableHeading.setAttribute("class", "divTableHeading");

  var row = document.createElement("DIV");
  row.setAttribute("class", "divTableRow");
  tableHeading.appendChild(row);
  likertTable.appendChild(tableHeading);
  main.appendChild(likertTable);

var tableHeader = ["Question", "Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Undecided", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree"];
  for (var i = 0; i < tableHeader.length; i++) {
   var tableCell = document.createElement("DIV");
   tableCell.setAttribute("class","divTableCell");
   row.appendChild(tableCell);
   tableCell.innerHTML = tableHeader[i];
   }
```

```css
.divTable{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
.divTableRow {
 display: table-row;
}
/*.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
}*/
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
 border: 1px solid #999999;
 display: table-cell;
 padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
 background-color: #EEE;
 display: table-footer-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
```

The actual variable is `var tableHeader = [ranges];` and it works just fine as seen in the screen capture and the snippet correctly appends if a regular HTML table is generated with a TH rather than DIV tag.

Where am I going wrong? Oh shoot!!! Asked an answered! `var tableHeader = [ranges];` should have been `var tableHeader = ranges;`

Came home as the script ran perfectly in snippets editor.

Thanks StackOverflow.

Comment: Try work around with CSS for DIV as you stated it works fine with TH.

Comment: @smkrn110 , thanks for your answer. Please see my answer. It was an error on my part enclosing a variable for an array in square brackets [ranges] instead of just typing ranges. This resulted in [[item, item 2, item3]] instead of [item, item 2, item3]. The trial with TH had used a hard coded array rather than processing a POST var.  Best.

Answer (score 0):

`var tableHeader = [ranges];` should have been `var tableHeader = ranges;` as the former placed the array in two pairs of square brackets without throwing an error in the console.